# Nested WITH blocks

Tags: vb.net

How to access to an external WITH block?

```
With New Object() {1, 2}
    Dim debug_1 As Object = .ToArray(0) 'Ok - got 1 from object
    With New Object() {3, 4}
         Dim debug_2 As Object = .ToArray(0)  'Got 3
         'How get 2 from WITH block Object() {1, 2}?
         '>>>
    End With
End With
```

Comment: This is not a solution. This is an alternative and declaration of additional variables :)

Comment: Then, what would you like the solution to be if the language doesn't support what you're asking?

Comment: Nested `With` statements only work if the expression used in the second `With` statement starts with a dot and extends the expression used in the first `With` statement. That's it, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Declare a variable instead, it'll make the code more readable

```
Dim x = New Object() {1, 2}
Dim debug_1  = x(0) 'Ok - got 1 from object
Dim y = New Object() {3, 4}
Dim debug_2 As y(0)  'Got 3

'How get 2 from WITH block Object() {1, 2}?
x(1)
```

No indents, no wondering "is the leading dot on this line of code the first object or the second, third, fourth..." multiple nested With are a serious impediment to readable code and should be avoided

Comment: How is this any different from the answer to the dup?

Comment: I use the mobile site; at the time I wrote this answer there was no dup. The linked duplicate still features a With and it's With'd on items that already exist as variable references. The OP's question doesn't feature similarly

Comment: Dim x  dim y - Ingenious :))

Comment: Yes, I picked similarly descriptive, self documenting names as might befit the example Objects :)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution ;)**

```
With New Object() {1, 2}    
    With New Object() {3, 4}.Concat(.ToArray)
         Dim debug_0 As Object = .ToArray(3)  'Got 2
    End With
End With
```